# タブをダブルクリックしても別のグループで開かないようにしたい

Tags: emeditor

技術的なフィードバックはこちらでとのことで書き込みします。

EmEditorのタブテキストを選択する際、間違ってダブルクリックすることがあるのですが、
このときタブテキストがオープンになって、別グループのウィンドウで開いてしまいます。
タブテキストは手動で並び順に設定してあるので、戻すのにいちいちドロップして、定位置にセットしなおさないといけなく、これにかかる時間がもったいなくてイライラします。

設定でこの機能を無効にするとかできないでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

ごめんなさい。投稿直後に自己解決しました。

こちらに答えがありました。

[タブをダブルクリックした際の挙動 - EmEditor](https://jp.emeditor.com/forums/topic/%E3%82%BF%E3%83%96%E3%82%92%E3%83%80%E3%83%96%E3%83%AB%E3%82%AF%E3%83%AA%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E9%9A%9B%E3%81%AE%E6%8C%99%E5%8B%95/)

ツール→カスタマイズ→マウスの
マウス左ボタンをダブルクリックで挙動を設定できるようで、
デフォルトで新しいグループになってました。

これを「未定義」とかに設定すると、回避できるようです。

なお、現バージョン20.8.1です。

同じ症状でお困りの方、お試しください。

**クローズの仕方わかんないので、本件クローズとしてください。**

失礼しました。